# Passing return value into another method

Tags: ruby

I am starting with an array of letters:

```
letters = %w[c s t p b l f g d m  
             y o u i h t r a e l 
             o t l a e m r s n i 
             m a y l p x s e k d]
```

Passing them, finding all combinations that return an array like this `["cstp", "cstb", "cstl"]`, this is a shortened example.

```
def combinations(letters)
  combos = letters.combination(4) 
  combos.collect do |letter_set|
    letter_set.join(",").gsub("," ,"")  
  end
end
```

I am trying to figure out how to pass the return value of `combinations` into `start_wtih_letter_c`. Do I have to pass a block like `&block`? I tried various things that keep saying wrong number of arguments.

```
def start_with_letter_c(pass the return value)
  combinations.select {|word| word.match(/^ca/) }
end
```

Comment: It's not clear what the issue is; you have a value you can pass, why can't you pass it in? How are you *calling* `start_with_letter_c`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go, no errors:

```
letters = %w[c s t p b l f g d m  
             y o u i h t r a e l 
             o t l a e m r s n i 
             m a y l p x s e k d]

def combinations(letters)
  combos = letters.combination(4) 
  combos.collect do |letter_set|
    letter_set.join(",").gsub("," ,"")  
  end
end

def start_with_letter_c(combinations)
  combinations.select {|word| word.match(/^ca/) }
end

start_with_letter_c(combinations(letters))
# => ["cael", "caeo", "caet", "cael", "ca ...and so on
```

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't passing in letters when calling combinations.

Answer (score 3):

I would write something like this:

```
letters = %w[c s t p b l f g d m  
             y o u i h t r a e l 
             o t l a e m r s n i 
             m a y l p x s e k d]

def combinations(letters)
  letters.combination(4).map(&:join) 
end

def start_with_letter_c(combinations)
  combinations.select { |word| word.start_with?('ca') }
end

start_with_letter_c(combinations(letters))
```

Comment: I like how you used `start_with?`, as it is easier to understand its meaning than a regex method.

Comment: @HunterStevens: And the `start_with?` method is faster than the regexp version as a bonus...

Comment: You don't need `combos =`.